# SAP Cloud SDK for Javascript: difference between pre-delivered OData services VS self-generated clients

Tags: javascript, sap-cloud-sdk

Is there any difference (extra-code) between the predelivered OData client services and the ones I would have generated myself using @sap-cloud-sdk/generator, provided I have the exact same OData service version?
From my unit test of BusinessPartner, it looks it works the same. Can anyone confirm?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The code that we ship in packages like `@sap/cloud-sdk-vdm-business-partner-service` is the exact same code you'd get if you generated it yourself, based on the service definition from api.sap.com.

We obviously generate some more things on the side, like a `package.json` and documentation and so on, but the code is identical.